# Best way to write a ftp client program to list files on the server?

Tags: c, windows, ftp, client-server, winsock2

I am trying to write a client-server program in C in windows. The objective is to receive the directory listing from the server. Now I was trying to develop the client-server in such a way to utilize most resources.

One way to implement is that server makes a single send() call to send info of a single file. So if there are 100 files, it makes 100 calls. But I feel its a wastage of network resources. As far as I know the buffer size for send() or recv() in windows is 8kb. But the info of a single file will be hardly 1kb. So is there a way to make send() call to send multiple files info (file info are stored in structures. So they basically form a linked list) ? May be I can send info of atleast 8 files in a single Send() call. That should reduce the total send() calls to maximum 13.

So basically is there a way to send a linked list via send() ?? Plz let me know if you can think of any alternative method.

Answer (score 1):

Good question! +1 for that.

But do you really want or need to write your code to use Winsock? There are good reasons to do so -- including that it's fun and a challenge. But if you don't need to, you might want to consider using the [**libcurl ftp library**](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html), which is free, multi-platform (including win32, of course), just works, and might make your job a lot easier.

Comment: thanks, but I need to write the code using winsock. Its actually a part of the application I am developing. So any idea in this direction would be helpful.

Comment: Just to beat this dead horse one more time, libcurl does indeed use winsock; but libcurl handles the details. You might consider it a wrapper for winsock.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to do this with FTP is to use multiple connections to the FTP server.  If this is allowed by the server, there can be a list performance boost because the many protocol exchanges needed to list a complete folder tree can be run in parallel.

Rgds,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

TCP is a byte stream. There is no guarantee of a 1-to-1 relation between the number of items you want to send and the number of calls to `send()` (or `recv()`) you need to make. That is simply not how TCP works. You format the data the way you need to, and then you keep calling `send()` until it tells you that all of the data has been sent.

Regarding FTP, please read [RFC 959](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0959.txt) and [RFC 3659](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3659.txt) to learn how the ftp protocol actually works. Before the introduction of the `MLST` and `MLSD` commands, directory listings had no standardized format. FTP servers were free to use whatever formatting they wanted. Many servers just piped the raw data from the OS's own `dir` or `list` commands. [Indy](http://www.indyproject.org), for example, includes several dozen parsers in its FTP client for handling non-standard directory listings.